# How to make v-model dynamic in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJs: 2.3.3 to build form dynamically and Vee-Validate: 2.0.0-beta.17 to validate input fields according to this [tutorial](https://m.dotdev.co/form-validation-using-vue-js-2-35abd6b18c5d) :

```
<form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">
  <div v-for="f in form.fields" class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has(f.model) }" >
    <label class="control-label">{{ f.label }}</label>
    <input v-model="f.model" v-validate.initial="f.model" :data-vv-rules="f.rules" class="form-control" type="email" :placeholder="f.placeholder">
    <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.has(f.model)">{{ errors.first(f.model) }}</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My vue instance has:

```
data(){
    return {
      form: {
        fields: [{
          model: 'email',
          rules: 'required|email',
          label: 'Email',
          placeholder: 'Email'
        }]
      }  
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't make my form works with vee-validation : When I add email directly to data like : `email: ''` (outside form) and change values of both `v-validate` and `data-rules` to `'email'` it works as expected but when I put dynamic values to these attributes it doesn't work. Can anyone help me to fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't `data-vv-rules` be just `data-rules`?

Comment: @wostex No, `data-vv-rules` works fine. When I put `data-rules` I got this error in my console : `Cannot read property 'split' of null`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/66/ fiddle. I get an error `v-model does not support dynamic input types. Use v-if branches instead.`

Comment: Exactly. I changed my code but still have same issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `vee-validate` to help you further. What the error means is that you should rewrite `v-model` into `:prop`-`@emit` pair: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Comment: I rewrite `v-model` with no luck :s @wostex